# ¿Como puedo eliminar el margin-left que tiene por defecto las etiquetas <a> del navbar de Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, navbar, margin, enlaces-ancla

No encuentro la manera de hacerlo desde CSS. Imagino que viene predeterminado por alguna de las clases de Bootstrap, pero imagino al mismo tiempo que debe poder editarse.
Como verán en esta foto, en el navbar todos los enlaces-ancla están tirados hacia la derecha en su contenedor, y en la próxima imagen se puede ver que tienen un margin left aplicado. Necesito eliminarlo para que el navbar en general se vea centrado en la página. ¿Pueden guiarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por defecto el a.nav-link está centrado en bootstrap, tu debes haber pisado alguna regla del css. Inspecciona el elemento en el navegador y mira donde está el margen

Comment: Ya que no veo ningún código de referencia, en tu etiqueta `<a>`, aplica la siguiente propiedad `margin:0 !important`.

Comment: Haz intentado acceder al elemento mediante la clase de bootstrap y modificar el estilos en CSS?, sin el código es difícil poder ayudarte, recuerda que puedes [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/555832/edit) tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.